Show that this family is a sigma algebra
Let $X$ a set, $\mathcal{F}\subseteq 2^X$ and $A\subseteq X$.
Define $\mathcal{M}=\{E\in\sigma(\mathcal{F}) \hspace{3pt} | \hspace{3pt} E\cap A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)\}$ where $\mathcal{F}_A=\{E\cap A\hspace{3pt} | \hspace{3pt} E\in \mathcal{F}\}$. Prove that $\mathcal{M}$ is a sigma algebra on $X$ that contains $\mathcal{F}$.
Here's my proof:
If $E\in \mathcal{F}$, then $E\cap A\in \mathcal{F}_A\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$, so $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{M}$.
Then, we have:

$X\in \mathcal{M}$ because $X\in \sigma(\mathcal{F})$ and $X\cap A=A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$.

Let $E\in \mathcal{M}$, then $E\in \sigma(\mathcal{F})$ and $E\cap A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$.
Because $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ is a sigma algebra on $A$, it's true that $A\setminus (E\cap A)=A\setminus E=A\cap (X\setminus E)\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ and because $X\setminus E\in \sigma(\mathcal{F})$, we have $X\setminus E\in \mathcal{M}$.

Let $(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $E_n\in \mathcal{M}, \hspace{3pt} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, $E_n\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}), \hspace{3pt}\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $E_n\cap A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)\hspace{3pt} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Because $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ is a sigma algebra on $A$, we have $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (E_n\cap A)=\left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}E_n\right)\cap A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ and because $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E_n\in \sigma(\mathcal{F})$, we have $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E_n\in \mathcal{M}$.


Is this correct? Could it be written in a shorter way? And, I have a doubt on the way I concluded that $X\in \mathcal{M}$, is it sufficient?

Does $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ mean the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}_A$ in $A$ or the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}_A$ in $X$?

If $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}_A$ in $X$, then $A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ may not be true.

I need this fact to prove that $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)=\sigma(\mathcal{F})_A$, so, because the right hand side is a sigma algebra on $A$, I think that
$\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ must be a sigma algebra on $A$. But, it could also be a sigma algebra on $X$, given that $\mathcal{F}_A\subseteq 2^A\subseteq 2^X$.

Or am I wrong to say this?

Here are some important remarks.
Remark 1:
If $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}_A$ in $X$, then $A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ may not be true. Here is a simple counter-example:

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$,  $\mathcal{F}= \{\{1\}\}\subseteq 2^X$ and $A=\{1,2\}\subseteq X$. Then $\mathcal{F}_A=\{E\cap A\hspace{3pt} | \hspace{3pt} E\in \mathcal{F}\}= \{\{1\}\}$.
If $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}_A$ in $X$, then $$\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A) = \{\emptyset,\{1\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$$
So $A \notin \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$

Since we need $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$, there are two obvious solutions:

require that $A \in \mathcal{F}$ or
consider that $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}_A$ in $A$. In this case, in the above counter-example, we would have $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A) = \{\emptyset,\{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$.

Remark 2: If $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}_A$ in $A$, then your proof correct. Note that, your proof with minor adjustment in the argument to prove the complement property and in the countable union property, would also work using only the assumption of $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$, no matter if $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ is considering regarding $A$ or $X$.
Moreover, since you proved $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{M} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{F})$ and you proved $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have $\sigma(\mathcal{F})\subseteq \mathcal{M} $. So, you actually proved that $\mathcal{M}= \sigma(\mathcal{F})$.
Remar 3: A more general (and slightly easier to prove) result is:

Let $X$ a set, $\mathcal{F}\subseteq 2^X$ and $A\subseteq X$.
Define $\mathcal{N}=\{E \subseteq X  \hspace{3pt} | \hspace{3pt} E\cap A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)\}$ where $\mathcal{F}_A=\{E\cap A\hspace{3pt} | \hspace{3pt} E\in \mathcal{F}\}$.
If $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$, then $\mathcal{N}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that contains $\mathcal{F}$.

Proof:
If $E\in \mathcal{F}$, then $E\cap A\in \mathcal{F}_A\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$, so $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{N}$.
Then, we have:

$X\in \mathcal{N}$ because $X\cap A=A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$.

Let $E\in \mathcal{N}$, then $E\cap A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$.
Because $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$, it's true that $A\setminus (E\cap A)=A\setminus E=A\cap (X\setminus E)\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$, so we have $X\setminus E\in \mathcal{N}$.

Let $(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $E_n\in \mathcal{N}, \hspace{3pt} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, $E_n\cap A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)\hspace{3pt} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Because $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (E_n\cap A)=\left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}E_n\right)\cap A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$, so we have $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E_n\in \mathcal{M}$.


Note that since $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{N} $ and we have proved $\mathcal{N}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have $\sigma(\mathcal{F})\subseteq \mathcal{N}$. It is clear $\mathcal{M}$ as defined in the question is $\mathcal{N} \cap \sigma(\mathcal{F})$.

So, using that $A\in \sigma(\mathcal{F}_A)$, I can directly conclude on the other two points of the definition of sigma algebra using that the difference and unions/intersections (at most countably infinite) of elements of a sigma algebra are still elements of that sigma algebra?

@SigmaAlgebra , Right.

Thank you a lot!
